# Formal quotation of smooth random terms in mgcv::gam mixed model

Tags: mixed-models, gam, mgcv

I have a mgcv::gam mixed model of the form:

```
m1 <- gam(Y ~ A + s(B, bs = "re"), data = dataframe, family = gaussian,
 method = "REML")
```

The random term `s(B, bs = "re")` is quoted in `summary(m1)` as, for example,

```
Approximate significance of smooth terms:
           # edf Ref.df      F p-value   
s(B)  4.486      5 97.195 6.7e-08 ***
```

My question is, how would I quote this result (statistic and P value) in a formal document, for example a technical report or paper?

For example, one possibility is

> F[4.486,5] = 97.195, P = 6.7e-08

However, arguing against this idea, “reverse engineering” of the result using

```
pf(q= 97.195, df1= 4.486, df2= 5, lower.tail=FALSE)
```

gives an incorrect p value:

```
[1] 5.931567e-05
```

I would be very grateful for your advice. Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The F statistic in question doesn't actually follow an F with the degrees of freedom you have identified. The `Ref df` one is related to the test, but you'd need to read and understand Wood (2013) to fully grep how the degrees of freedom for the test are derived.

I would simply quote the statistic and the p-value and then cite Simon's paper if anyone wants to know how they were computed. I don't think you can easily get at the degrees of freedom that actually get used. (well, not without debugging the `summary.gam()` code and seeing how they are computed.)

#### References

Wood, S. N. 2013. A simple test for random effects in regression models. Biometrika 100: 1005–1010. doi:10.1093/biomet/ast038

Comment: Thanks very much, Gavin! I had a look at Simon's paper and dug around in the innards of `summary.gam()` but had no luck understanding how to get df1 and df2 for the quoted F ratio. I will try and look at these things at more leisure in the future.